# og:image Open Graph Warnings image size

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, resolution

I check my url because facebook don't use the image that I set on og:image

[url fb check](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.filmopis.com%2Flistaomiljenih.php%3Fmlista%3D165)

My image is: 639x649px 486kb
But fb use this picture: 300x443px 97kb

The warning said:

> og:image should be larger:    Provided og:image is not big enough. Please
>   use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500.
>   (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image
>   'url from image, size: 300x443px 97kb'
>   will be used instead.

But when I try to create an image 1500x1500px, upload to server, refresh, and check again the link on top, the results are the same.

Comment: I am having the same issue here, i had 200x200 images and larger than 200x200 ones, when i comment the image does not show up, but when i run the debugger on the url, it shows the image and then shows the size warning. however when i then refresh my fb profile page the image shows up after running debugger tool on url. very strange...

Answer (score 80, accepted):

My experience with Facebook made me doubt that computers are deterministic machines :)

Sometimes it will accept image of any size (between 200 and 1500px), sometimes complain that image is too small (*og:image should be larger*) even if image **is squared** and **bigger than minimum size** (e.g. 400x400px). 
I had situations where the same link showed all 3 og:images in linter and in FB status field, then suddenly 2 weeks later stopped working and started showing only one image while trying to share it in FB status field (linter still showed all 3 images), and vice versa.
Sometimes FB seems to have problems with different domains (e.g. page is on www.example.com and og:image on www.picdumpexamplesite.com), sometimes it doesn't mind...

IMHO it's heavily broken, and the best you can do is:
- make images squared, rounded to "hundreds", e.g. size 300x300px
- host them on the same server (same domain name)
- use jpg
- avoid any "strange" chars in filename (I use only letters and numbers)
- pray that something of the above works :)

Comment: Of the suggestions here, it was rounding it to hundreds that made that error go away for me. i had an image that was 1299px x 1299px and it said it wasn't big enough. changed it to 1300px sqared and the error went away.

Comment: I had trouble with this too. I was about to give up, and deleted the other og:image tags to force the one and only to be used - even after doing so, it still said it was going to use the other that was no longer specified ?!?
So I reloaded once more to try and clear the debuggers cache - the error went away, then I added the other images, the error was still gone and it works now!

Comment: Rounding to hundreds worked for me, without needing to "square" the image.  I moved from 801px x 397px to 800px x 400px and that solved the problem.

Comment: There are a lot nondeterministic automata implementations, so every machine doesnt have to be necessarily deterministic ;)

Comment: You're correct even a year later, absolutely inconsistent random results.

Comment: So I have tried all of these solutions, is there an answer?

Comment: Have you tried to specify image properties?
_Example from OpenGraph documentation:_

`<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />`

Comment: I have noticed that URLs with double slashes (ie malformatted) is sensitive for the scraper. Make sure there are no such errors, eg https://foo.bar//image.jpg

Comment: @TristanLeblanc It can help to specify the dimensions, it makes the image appear the first time a URL is shared. See "Pre-caching images", https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

Answer (score 21):

Here's my tale of woe, hopefully it helps someone else.

I was getting similar warnings:

```
Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at
least 200x200 px.
```

but this was only occurring on some pages of our website and not others. Which was strange, since the CMS we use consistently puts a `427px x 307px` image on every page, and uses the URL to this image as the `og:image` tag.

After trying the hints above, I ended up comparing the JPG files on the pages that worked vs. the JPG files on the pages that didn't work and found those that didn't work had EXIF metadata in them. I removed the metadata in Photoshop, updated the webpages and resubmitted the pages to the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it worked.

**tl;dr** - Remove EXIF data from og:image.

Comment: Worked for me. This helped too: https://photographylife.com/how-to-delete-exif-data

Answer (score 15):

I had

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

in the meta tags.

Removed that line and it worked.

Current tags now look like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Here" />       
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/images/myimage.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Facebook will often clear the image size error on the second scrape of the URL, in my experience. It gives the error on the first scrape of images of any size.
The problem I have is that it ends up using the image and cropping it arbitrarily into 2:1 for use in page posts.

Comment: Second scrape using the debug tool (Open Graph Object Debugger) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found by adding the following additional tags worked for me ...

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1280" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="855" />
```

as mentioned in post [Facebook linter reports og:image is too small, when it is larger than the image it choose instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004288/facebook-linter-reports-ogimage-is-too-small-when-it-is-larger-than-the-image)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, but I also didn't have an `og:description`.  Once I added a description, the image worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many of the suggestions on this post and others to no avail. The solution (which I have not seen elsewhere) was to add the correct prefix to the `<head>` element which I had previously omitted entirely.

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

I'm uncertain if that actually fixed the problem for good or if it has forced the debugger into properly re-scanning the image. Hopefully this solution will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had similar problems. As a rule of thumb, use JPG instead PNG files.

The problem with PNG files is the transparent background. They cannot properly calculate the height and weight.

It's a pity that it is not specified on the documentation...

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to set up the large image preview mode but it wasn't working even though my image resolution was big enough (1200x630). Changing the image format to jpg fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think SeeBeen is right. I've found that Facebook prefers numbers rounded to the hundreds, and doesn't seem to care so much whether the images are square.

For instance, it will properly select an image that is 700x300, rather than one that is 610x281 (these are actual examples from my tests). I was having an issue where the og:image was 610x281, and FB would choose the 300x600 banner ads from our sidebar instead, completely ignoring the og:image. When I changed the raw image file to 700x300, it worked fine.

I imagine this will change soon, but for now (March 2013) it seems to work.

Comment: From an article at AListApart (http://alistapart.com/article/like-able-content-spread-your-message-with-third-party-metadata): "IMAGE SELECTION
Effective, appropriate images can make the difference between a friend avoiding or clicking on a link in her news feed. Image guidelines for article-type pages in OG are pretty straightforward: 200×200px minimum with a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. However, a square image will allow the best use of the space. Twitter cards resize any image over 120×120px, so you would be safe using that same 200×200px image you’ve already created for your og:image."

Answer (score 0):

Idea about 100 rounding and square is not true. I don't know where did you get that. Look at this web. Try to debug the URL http://www.stipendije.ba/novost/1969

It might also be up to "strong" colors, huge contrast and strange characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using the Facebook URL Debugger to force the refresh of the cache of the **canonical URL.** This was the trick. I was trying to refresh a URL that was not the exact canonical URL (it was missing the trailing forward slash). Once I fetched the new meta data of the correct URL everything was resolving and displaying correctly.