# og:image should be larger

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm not sure why, but I keep getting this warning when using the [OG Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and Facebook doesn't load the correct error. It's telling me the image isn't large enough, but the image is 404x404px, so I'm not sure what it's expecting, since it meets the 200x200 preference.

Here's the fully reported meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://beta.ccchapel.com/getattachment/1fc7e302-342f-4b1e-aae3-466905d3e084/" />
```

Any help of suggestions you may have would be appreciated.

Comment: I also have had the same issue but I was using an image that is 800x500 yet I am told the image is too small?

Comment: can you give your pages full url so that i can debug it in facebook debugger

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following option to get rid of it:-

- make images squared, rounded to "hundreds", e.g. size 300x300px
- host them on the same server (same domain name)
- use jpg
- avoid any "strange" chars in filename

Reference [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421521/ogimage-open-graph-warnings-image-size)

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding the meta fields for "manually" specifying height and width?

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="404">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="404">
```

Comment: I have done this and it doesn't make a difference in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same error.. Here is what I have done.

From Facebook Documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/612/

> When modifying Open Graph objects, you will need to tell Facebook’s
>   scraper to rescrape your page to pull in the updated information.
>   There are a couple different ways to have your object re-scraped.
>
> 1. Manually using the debugger at
>      https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug This will pull in a
>      fresh copy of your page’s data if you are an admin or developer of
>      the object, as determined by the fb:app_id or fb:admins meta tag.
> 2. More automated by using the "scrape=true" POST parameter. Make a
>      POST call to https://graph.facebook.com/?id={id}&scrape=true where
>      {id} is the object id or the url of the object. The response is a
>      JSON object with the data scraped for the url.

Also, while using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug I keep on reptrying until it accepted all of a sudden. Also Using the second option is more reliable, I think

Reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/