# Sharing og:image should be larger?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

For Sharing Newsletter-Contents, I have created special pages with sharing information, e.g. this one:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jaegermeister.de%2Fnewsletter%2FJM_NL_112013%2Ffb_share_shop.html

The open graph object debugger always warns that the sharing-image should be larger. I tried different sizes, all 200x200px and much larger, tried all options written in this thread ([og:image should be larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555436/ogimage-should-be-larger)), but the warning never disappears and the wrong image will be shared.

What is wrong with that? I just don't get it! We've done this for several newsletters before and never had any problems with that. In the object properties of the object debugger the image is the right one...

I look forward to any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook debugger caches things... a lot. Wait 24-48 hours for the debugger to reflect the changes. Even if you are an administrator of the object, it has a habit of not clearing the cache.

But, when I click on the debugger link you provided, there's no image warning.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Probably it was really a caching issue. Now I don't see the warning anymore, too. And sharing works correct now. 

Thank you!!